# Cannot Delete Samba 4 AD User Groups

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba

So I created a Active Director Domain Controller on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, and everything works great except I don't seem to be able to delete anything.

I connected my Windows 10 machine to the domain, and everything works there. I am using RSAT to manage the users and computers, and I've also successfully added my Macbook as well.

But, when I look at the users list, I see this:

[image]

When trying to delete one of those groups, I get this:

[image]

Now, here are my questions:

Where is this group list being populated from?

Where on my Ubuntu server could I go and manage this list?

Are these groups not meant to be deleted? If so, is it a best practices thing, or are they just not able to be deleted?

What is this error I am getting mean? I have a 1TB hard drive on the machine, and just cleanly installed everything...is that the kind of storage it is talking about?

Did I miss something when reading the Samba wiki?

New to ServerFault, but not StackEnchange, so sorry if this is in the wrong area.

Edit: should probably mention that I can add users, groups and computers without fail. This storage error doesn't show up at all during those processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These groups are not meant to be deleted.  They are used by Active Directory for user permissions.  For example, a member of the Schema Admins group can work with the AD Schema (such as extending the Schema for new features ie LAPS).  They are all built into AD, created when the domain was created, and should not be deleted.

Comment: Alright thanks. So this isn't an issue with the Ubuntu setup, but rather just the AD not letting me delete them because it's not supposed to?

Comment: That's my take on the situation, although I've never used AD on Linux (it's on my to do list).  My guess would be the error being thrown "Out of Space" is just because of the way the permissions are set up to disable deletion.